# How to disable horizontal tap if content fits to mobile screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, viewport

Bootstrap 3 shopping cart is defined using bootstrap standard markup like

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<body>    
    <div class="container">
        <div id="_info"></div>

        <header class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
    </header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">L&#252;li navigeerimist</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li>

      ....
```

In mobile its content width is same as mobile screen width.

However user can drag content horizontally left so that ugly white space appears in left.

How to fix this so that unnessecary left dragging is not allowed?
Maybe some element in page causes this effect?

I tried to delete elements in Chrome developer tools Elements tab but horizontal scroling is still allowed.

Comment: And here is the problem: http://i.imgur.com/m6f3bRW.png

Comment: In some pages horizontal scroll is requred so it cannot disabled always. I expect that it will be disabled automatically by browser if it is not required. Wide element in provided picture pointed is created probably by facebook script. How to force facebook to create proper width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your header and footer both have a hard set width to them. This would normally not be an issue with proper media queries but in my opinion in order to not have to worry about adding more media queries I would just change your CSS for the header like I have below:

```
@media only all and (min-width: 481px)
    header, .wrap {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

For the footer, you have a facebook toolbar that has a lot of hardset inline widths. You can hack this together by wrapping the entire element in a div and applying `width: 100%; overflow: hidden;` to that div but I would strongly recommend you do more research on that plugin to make it function properly or find a better plugin that will give you better results.

Comment: Thank you. Insted of width: 100% I removed width from style as described in Valius79 answer. Is this OK ?

Answer (score 0):

This did it on my comp. I just disabled the set width of the header.